# PyBeacon eddystone-UID

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, eddystone

i'm trying use PyBeacon package to make some Eddystone-UID using Raspberry PI 3+ device. Executing PyBeacon -i 321654987654321a321654a456b54699 command, for example, and using the Google App called "Beacon Tools" to register the Eddystone-UID beacon (ok detected into unregistered layer), when i try to register, the app tell me "failed to connect".

When i use a hardware beacon with Eddystone support, i must to config each beacon in "configure mode" to can access OK using the app.

Is it possible register into Google Beacon Plataform the eddystone beacons created using PyBeacon package?

thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

The user interface for the Beacon Tools app is confusing.  It does two very different things:

1. Registration - this sets up the beacon on Google's servers and ties it to your Google account.
2. Provisioning - this tries to set the beacon hardware configuration (identifiers, transmission rate, etc.) on the physical hardware beacon itself by connecting to the beacon hardware over a bluetooth connection.  This only works on a hardware beacons that implement Google's Eddystone Bluetooth GATT registration service. (Most hardware beacons don't even do this.) And even then, this only works when you beacon is in configurable mode.

The fact that you see "failed to connect" suggest you are doing 2 when really what you want to do is 1.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your reply.
Like you told before, i was trying register the beacon into Google Plataform. I needed register the beacon to make function OK nearby notification when i use PyBeacon into a RPI 3+ is activated with the beacon_number advertising.

Actually i can register the beacons using the script Python (from https://github.com/google/beacon-platform/tree/master/samples/python). It work ok and i can integrate into an mkt site.